# Passing Form object when using Ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have a complex form for a survey. A survey

```
belongs_to :template
has_many :questions, :through => :template
has_many :answers, :through => :questions
```

I.e. User creates a new survey, and he must select a survey template. The survey template will create some default questions and answer fields.

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>

  <p>Select a template:</p>
  <%= render @templates, :locals => {:patient => @patient }, :f => f %>

<% end %>
```

Then I render the `_templates` partial, and I still have access to the form object. From here, the idea is that a user can click on a template name, and the template questions and answers will be rendered via Ajax.

```
<% @templates.each do |template| %>

  <div class="thumbnail">
    <%= link_to template.name,
                { :controller => "surveys",
                  :action => "new",
                  :template_id => template.id,
                  :patient_id => nil,
                  :f => f,
                  :remote=> true },
                :class=> "template", :id=> template.id %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**surveys#new:**

```
respond_to :js, :html

def new
  @template = Template.find(params[:template_id])
  @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
end
```

**new.js.erb:**

```
$('#assessment').append("<%= j (render new_survey_path, :locals => {:f => f} ) %>");
```

**new_survey_path:**

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
  <% @template.questions.where(category:"S").each do |question| %>
     <p><%= question.content %></p>
     <%= render 'answer_fields', :question=> question %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I'm having trouble passing the original `|f|` object from `@survey` to `new_survey_path`. The last place I can access the form object is in the templates partial.

How can I fix this?